# How to add values to JSONObject on button click in android?

Tags: android, json, android-studio, android-json

i have an adapter from which i am creating edittext for user to input data dynamically.

Now, i have to store the same in JSONObject in a key-value pair?
how can i do it?

i am storing all the created edit text in a list

```
ArrayList<EditText> list = new ArrayList<>();
```

*EDIT PART*

i am adding edittext to list like this:

```
list.add(holder.editText);
```

*EDIT PART -ENDS*

this is my button click listener code:

```
addnewAcnt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                Toast.makeText(context, "INIT", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                JSONObject jsonObject2 = null;
                for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
                {
                    jsonObject2 = new JSONObject();
                    try
                    {
                        jsonObject2.put(String.valueOf(list.get(i).getHint()), String.valueOf(list.get(i).getText()));
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        Log.e("JsonToSendError: ", String.valueOf(e));
                    }

                    Log.e("JsonToSend: ", String.valueOf(jsonObject2));
                }
            }
        });
```

I am getting data in Log as:

```
2020-10-05 15:19:21.476 16462-16462/com.packagename E/JsonToSend:: {"Title":"StackOverFlow"}
2020-10-05 15:19:21.476 16462-16462/com.packagename E/JsonToSend:: {"URL":"www.stackoverflow.com"}
2020-10-05 15:19:21.476 16462-16462/com.packagename E/JsonToSend:: {"Username":"test"}
2020-10-05 15:19:21.476 16462-16462/com.packagename E/JsonToSend:: {"Password":"testtesttest"}
```

But, i need it to be in a single object like:

```
{"Title":"StackOverFlow", "URL":"www.stackoverflow.com", "Username":"test", "Password":"testtesttest"}
```

any help will be useful.
Please

Comment: Because you creating new object in loop, try moving your `jsonObject2 = new JSONObject();` before the loop.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that fixes everything, Now i am not able to get value of last object
`{"Title":"StackOverFlow", "URL":"www.stackoverflow.com", "Username":"test", "Password":""}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you creating new object in loop, try moving your `jsonObject2 = new JSONObject();` before the loop.

About the last object, i'm not sure how do variable `count` value is changed. But if you are getting value from list, you should use that list count in your loop.

The code should be like this.

```
addnewAcnt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                Toast.makeText(context, "INIT", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                JSONObject jsonObject2 = new JSONObject();
                for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) // variable count to be your list (edit text) size.
                {
                    try
                    {
                        jsonObject2.put(String.valueOf(list.get(i).getHint()), list.get(i).getText().toString().trim());
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        Log.e("JsonToSendError: ", String.valueOf(e));
                    }

                    Log.e("JsonToSend: ", String.valueOf(jsonObject2));
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: I tried, still the same! i eve tried with dataModelArrayList(from model and adapters)
still the same!  :(

Comment: @Test i editted my answer, try it using `.getText().toString()`.

Comment: Still same brother, 1 thing i noticed, if i press submit button(of keyboard) it iterates to next edittext but before password field, it doesn't iterates to next edittext that is password field!

Comment: Weird, the json object key is gotten from hint of password field already but the value is not retrieved. Mind to share the full code?

Comment: No issues,
Which part do you want me to share?

Comment: I have edited my question, will you please check brother?

Comment: Seems like the code is in an adapter. So you have 4 lines of `list.add(holder.editText);` to add the edittext?

Comment: Yes, 4 times it is repeated in for loop!

Comment: Hmmm, is there any exception thrown in logcat?

Comment: Nooo!! thats what is bothering me!

Comment: Try to logging the value of your edittext in `try { }` before or after `jsonObject2.put()`

Comment: Thanks a lot brother, Solved had to do this!
`for (int i = 0; i <= list.size(); i++)`

Answer (score 0):

i think you need define `jsonObject2 = new JSONObject();` outside callback onclick. Hope this is helpful for you.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that fixes everything, but now i am not able to get value of last object
`{"Title":"StackOverFlow", "URL":"www.stackoverflow.com", "Username":"test", "Password":""}`

Comment: call `Log.e("JsonToSend: ", String.valueOf(jsonObject2));` outside forloop

Answer (score 0):

You create JSON object before the for loop
and initialize in for loop. which is wrong

initialize a JSON object before FOR loop

Change this line **jsonObject2 = null;** to **jsonObject2 = new JSONObject();**
and remove from FOR Loop

```
addnewAcnt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                Toast.makeText(context, "INIT", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                jsonObject2 = new JSONObject();


                for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
                {
                    //jsonObject2 = new JSONObject();
                    try
                    {
                        jsonObject2.put(String.valueOf(list.get(i).getHint()), String.valueOf(list.get(i).getText()));
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        Log.e("JsonToSendError: ", String.valueOf(e));
                    }

                    Log.e("JsonToSend: ", String.valueOf(jsonObject2));
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that fixes everything, but now i am not able to get value of last object
`{"Title":"StackOverFlow", "URL":"www.stackoverflow.com", "Username":"test", "Password":""}`